# Add html tag to JSLint

Tags: javascript, jslint

How can in add html tag to JSLint ?

I have some errors with the message :

```
 JSLint: Unrecognized tag 'foo'.
```

I would like to add the tag *foo* to the html_tag recognized by JSLint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this short of editing the JSLint source itself. If that is something you are willing to do, it's very straightforward. Just add your tag to the [`html_tag` object](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/d9c3940eaef07669324843394fae6c01f3146d6d/jslint.js#L751):

```
html_tag = {
    a:        {},
    abbr:     {},
    // etc...
},
// ...
```

However, I would consider what you're actually trying to achieve first... if the `foo` tag is not already in the list, it's not a valid HTML tag.

**However**... be aware that HTML support was removed from JSLint in [a recent commit](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/267939b9168419312782a8533e35c60243215d56). You will need to stay with an older version if you want this to work at all.